# Which rate of growth of the Sobolev norms guarantees analyticity?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, sobolev-spaces

Let $u\in C^\infty(\mathbb T^k)$, where $\mathbb T^k$ is the $k$-dimensional torus. (Equivalently, $u\in\mathbb R^k$ and $u$ is $2\pi$-periodic with respect of each argument.) 
We define the semi-norm 
$$
\|u\|_s=\|(-\Delta)^{s/2}u\|_{L^2(\mathbb T^k)}=\Big(\sum_{\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_k\in\mathbb Z}(\ell_1^2+\cdots+\ell^2_k)^{s/2}\big|\hat{u}_{\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_k}\big|^2\Big)^{1/2},
$$ 
where $s>0$ and $u(x_1,\ldots,x_k)=\sum_{\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_k\in\mathbb Z}\mathrm{e}^{2\pi i(\ell_1x_1+\cdots\ell_kx_k)}\hat{u}_{\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_k}$.

My question is the following: *Which rate of growth of $\|u\|_s$, as $s\to\infty$, implies that $u$ extends holomorphically to an open neighborhood of $\mathbb R^k$ in $\mathbb C^k$?*

More specifically: *Which rate of growth of $\|u\|_s$, as $s\to\infty$, guarantees that $u$ extends holomorphically to 
$$
\Omega_\alpha= \{(x_1+iy_1,\ldots,x_k+iy_k): x_1,y_1,\ldots,x_k,y_k\in\mathbb R\,\&\,|y_1|,\ldots,|y_k|<\alpha\} \subset \mathbb C^k,
$$
for a given $\alpha>0$.*

Comment: potentially related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space

Comment: Not the kind of answer I am looking for. I do know that the rate of growth is expected to be over-exponential, as exponential growth corresponds only to trigonometric polynomials.

Comment: Have a loot at volume 3 in Lions-Magenes' book **Non-Homogeneous Boundary Value Problems and Applications**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rate of growth must be $(cs)^s$ for some $c>0$.
In my sketch of the proof I assume for simplicity
that $k=1$ and Fourier coefficients $a_n$ are zero for $n<0$.

The function has an analytic extension in a neighborhood of the
unit circle if $|a_n|$ decrease faster than a geometric
progression, that is $\log |a_n|^2\leq-\delta n$ for some $\delta>0$.
Then your norm squared is
$$\Phi(s)=\sum_{1}^\infty n^s|a_n|^2\leq\sum e^{s\log n-\delta n}.$$
We consider this as a Dirichlet series of one complex variable $s$.
Let $m(s)$ be the maximal term of the sum in the RHS.
It is known from the theory of Dirichlet series that for every $\epsilon$
$$\Phi(s)\leq A(\epsilon)m(s+1+\epsilon).$$
The maximim term on the right hand side is found by calculus, by maximizing 
with respect to $n$, and we get
$$\Phi(s)\leq (cs)^s$$ for some $c>0.$

In the opposite direction, suppose that
 $\Phi(s)\leq (cs)^s$. Then
$$|a_n|^2n^s\leq (cs)^s.$$
This gives an estimate for $|a_n|$ with parameter $s$.
Minimizing with respect to $s$ 
we obtain the desired $\log|a_n|\leq -\delta n$, for some $\delta>0$.

For the inequality from the theory of Dirichlet series
(this is also no more than calculus) I refer to
the proof of Theorem III.2.1 of S. Mandelbrojt, Series de Dirichlet. Principes
et methodes, Paris Gauthier-Villars, 1969. The only references
that I know are in French, Russian and Ukrainian, sorry.

Comment: Could you provide a russian reference?

Comment: MR0584943 Leontʹev, A. F. Ryady eksponent.

Comment: The formula is not explicitly written there, but the estimate is contained in page 177 of Leontiev.

Comment: How is $c$ related to $\alpha$?

Comment: Small $\alpha$ gives large $c$. According to my computation, $\alpha c$ is bounded above and below.